# How to detect why eclipse plugin is not started?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed ShellEd, it is visible in Help -> About Eclipse -> Installed Software. However is just not working. I look at .log file in workspace and it has no information about it.

In Host OSGI Console when I type `ss` or `status` or `bundled` or `packages` it is not displayed in the list.

Any idea how to find out why its not working?

**UPDATE:**

```
<your eclipse>/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfiguratior/bundles.info
```

has

```
net.sourceforge.shelled.core,2.0.0.201108181319,configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/241/data/-1888557091/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.core_2.0.0.201108181319.jar,4,false
net.sourceforge.shelled.doc,2.0.0.201108181319,configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/241/data/-1888557091/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.doc_2.0.0.201108181319.jar,4,false
net.sourceforge.shelled.ui,2.0.0.201108181319,configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/241/data/-1888557091/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.ui_2.0.0.201108181319.jar,4,false
```

however the jars are not anywhere in eclipse directory (i do have them, where to drop them?)

> net.sourceforge.shelled-site-2.0.0.zip/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.core_2.0.0.201108181319.jar net.sourceforge.shelled-site-2.0.0.zip/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.doc_2.0.0.201108181319.jar
>   net.sourceforge.shelled-site-2.0.0.zip/plugins/net.sourceforge.shelled.ui_2.0.0.201108181319.jar
>
> net.sourceforge.shelled-site-2.0.0.zip/features/net.sourceforge.shelled_2.0.0.201108181319.jar

Answer (score 1):

Check it in file `<your eclipse>/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfiguratior/bundles.info`. You can manually add it if it's missing as workaround.

Comment: It's weired. Why were they installed into osgi's cache? Could you check the property `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.installFolder` in file `<your eclipse>\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\<name>.profile\<latest timestamp>.profile.gz` that is a compressed file?